# Jerky NSScrollView scrolling at certain angles on Yosemite (when using layers)

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollview with a large canvas that can be scrolled and zoomed etc. When I scroll diagonally at an angle of around 20 degrees from vertical it's really jerky (using a track pad.) This jerkiness even continues as the scrolling animates to rest.

All other angles of scroll are buttery smooth - which makes me think it's got something to do with a preference for vertical scrolling (predominant axis scrolling is disabled.)

The effect only seems to happen when I'm using layer backed views.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed bug in OSX Yosemite (by Apple DTS)